# Ignore if variable does not exist

Tags: php, validation, unset

I check if all fields of a form are present. For that I have an error array.

But if the value from row `Geschlecht` is not `'Paar'`, then I have to ignore `Tag2`, `Monat2`, `Jahr2` and also `Gebdatum2` because they do not exist in my form if `Geschlecht` is `Mann` or `Frau`. Otherwise I get:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in…

I tried it with `unset` but it doesn't really work.

```
else if(isset($_POST['submit']) AND $_POST['submit']=='Daten ändern'){ 
    // Fehlerarray anlegen 
    $errors = array(); 

    if(!isset ($_POST['Email'], 
              $_POST['Show_Email'], 
              $_POST['PLZ'], 
              $_POST['Wohnort'], 
              $_POST['Geschlecht'], 
              $_POST['Tag'],
              $_POST['Monat'],
              $_POST['Jahr'], 
              $_POST['Tag2'],
              $_POST['Monat2'],
              $_POST['Jahr2'], 
              $_POST['MSN'])) 


        $errors = "Bitte benutzen Sie das Formular aus Ihrem Profil"; 


 else{ 

      $emails = array(); 
        $sql = "SELECT 
                       Email 
                FROM 
                       User 
               "; 
        $result = mysql_query($sql) OR die("<pre>\n".$sql."</pre>\n".mysql_error()); 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            $emails[] = $row['Email']; 

        $sql = "SELECT 
                       Email 
                FROM 
                       User 
                WHERE 
                       ID = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['UserID'])."'
               "; 
        $result = mysql_query($sql) OR die("<pre>\n".$sql."</pre>\n".mysql_error()); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

        if(trim($_POST['Email'])=='') 
            $errors[]= "Bitte geben Sie Ihre Email-Adresse ein."; 
        elseif(!preg_match('§^[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,4}$§', trim($_POST['Email']))) 
            $errors[]= "Ihre Email Adresse hat eine falsche Syntax."; 
        elseif(in_array(trim($_POST['Email']), $emails) AND trim($_POST['Email'])!= $row['Email'])
            $errors[]= "Diese Email-Adresse ist bereits vergeben."; 
        } 
        if(count($errors)){ 
            echo "Ihre Daten konnten nicht bearbeitet werden.<br>\n". 
                 "<br>\n"; 
            foreach($errors as $error) 

                echo $error."<br>\n"; 
            echo "<br>\n". 
                 "Zurück zum <a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\">Profil</a>\n";
        } 
        else{ 

         $Gebdatum = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $_POST['Jahr'], $_POST['Monat'], $_POST['Tag']);
         $Gebdatum2 = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $_POST['Jahr2'], $_POST['Monat2'], $_POST['Tag2']); 

        $sql = "UPDATE 
                        User 
                SET 
                        Email =  '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['Email']))."',
                        Show_Email = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['Show_Email']))."',
                        Wohnort = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['Wohnort']))."',
                        PLZ = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['PLZ']))."',
                        Geschlecht = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['Geschlecht']))."',
                        Gebdatum = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($Gebdatum))."',
                        Gebdatum2 = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($Gebdatum2))."',
                        MSN = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['MSN']))."'
                WHERE 
                        ID = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['UserID'])."'
               ";    
        mysql_query($sql) OR die("<pre>\n".$sql."</pre>\n".mysql_error()); 
        echo "Ihre Daten wurden erfolgreich gespeichert.<br>\n". 
             "Zurück zu <a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\">Mein Profil</a><br>\n";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Split the error checking up

```php
if(!isset ($_POST['Email'],     # Check fields that you always need
      $_POST['Show_Email'], 
      $_POST['PLZ'], 
      $_POST['Wohnort'], 
      $_POST['Geschlecht'], 
      $_POST['Tag'],
      $_POST['Monat'])
      $_POST['Jahr']
      $_POST['MSN']){ 

      $errors[] = "Bitte benutzen Sie das Formular aus Ihrem Profil"; 
      #     ^^^ $errors should always be an Array       
}
else
{
        # Do a separate check for Gender=Couple
        if($_POST['Geschlecht']=="Paar" && 
          !isset(
            $_POST['Tag2'],
            $_POST['Monat2'],
            $_POST['Jahr2'], 
          )
        ) {

             $errors[] = "Bitte benutzen Sie das Formular aus Ihrem Profil"; # Text sollte was Anderes sein für Paare... 
              #     ^^^ $errors should always be an Array
        }

}
```

#### Rewrite sql for Paare with an if-statement

Then you can do checks like:

```php
$sql = "UPDATE User SET ";
$sql .= "Email = '" . //.... email;
#   ^^^ add to string in PHP

if ($_POST['Geschlecht']=="Paar") { 
  $sql .=  " Gebdatum2 = '". //....  
}

$sql .= "WHERE ID = '". //...
```

#### But if this is a critical application...

Then you may need to pull `Geschlecht` from the database to get *trusted input* on whether this is a record for couple or a person, because you cannot trust the value of `$_POST['Geschlecht']`.

This does not apply if you want to allow the user to change `Geschlecht` using this form.

Answer (score 0):

thanks. i tried it as you say, but than i get an

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /customers/5/f/d/regio-privat.com/httpd.www/myprofile.php on line 146*

this is the line befor the check if Geschlecht == Paar

```
$errors[] = "Bitte benutzen Sie das Formular aus Ihrem Profil";
```

because i want allow the user to change the status i made it like this

```
elseif(isset($_POST['submit']) AND $_POST['submit']=='Daten ändern'){ 
            // Fehlerarray anlegen 
            $errors = array(); 
            // Prüfen, ob alle Formularfelder vorhanden sind 
            if(!isset ($_POST['Email'], 
                      $_POST['Show_Email'], 
                      $_POST['PLZ'], 
                      $_POST['Wohnort'], 
                      $_POST['Geschlecht'], 
                      $_POST['Tag'],
                      $_POST['Monat'],
                      $_POST['Jahr'], 
                      $_POST['MSN']) || ($geschlecht=='Paar' && !isset($_POST['Tag2'], $_POST['Monat2'],$_POST['Jahr2'])))


                // Ein Element im Fehlerarray hinzufügen 
                $errors = "Bitte benutzen Sie das Formular aus Ihrem Profil"; 
            else{ ...some email check....
```

this seems to work and the data will be written in the database the right way also when the user changes the status. i only get still some notices
while Geschlecht is Mann or Frau i get this

*Notice: Undefined variable: geschlecht in ...myprofile.php on line 142 Notice: Undefined index: Jahr2 in ...myprofile.php on line 186 Notice: Undefined index: Monat2 in ...myprofile.php on line 186 Notice: Undefined index: Tag2 in ...myprofile.php on line 186 Ihre Daten wurden erfolgreich gespeichert.*

and by Paar this

*Notice: Undefined variable: geschlecht in ...myprofile.php on line 142 Ihre Daten wurden erfolgreich gespeichert.*

the 'geschlecht' notice is related to this line

```
  $_POST['MSN']) || ($geschlecht=='Paar' && !isset($_POST['Tag2'], $_POST['Monat2'],$_POST['Jahr2'])))
```

and line 186 contains this

```
$Gebdatum2 = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $_POST['Jahr2'], $_POST['Monat2'], $_POST['Tag2']);
```

so i have to find a way to avoid this messages.